# ionic back button not appearing in tabbed view

Tags: ionic-framework

ionic back button not appearing in the tabbed view.
I have created the sample code in plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/AjROKkHp50yyI9gHPNp8?p=preview

I have separated the **signin and registration** pages in the tabbed view

**Back button is appearing, if write the html's inside the** `<ion-tab>`.But  It is disappearing, if the html's are in another file.

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-top">
      <ion-tab title="Login" href="#/page2/signin">                
       //<ion-nav-view name="page2-signin"></ion-nav-view>//
       <ion-content has-bouncing="false">
         <h2>login page</h2>
       </ion-content>           
      </ion-tab>
      <ion-tab title="Rigister" href="#/page2/signup">
        <ion-nav-view name="page2-signup"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>        
    </ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

After referring your plunker code, it seems like you are adding tabs and referring the page something like below code.

```
<ion-nav-view name="page2-signin"></ion-nav-view>
```

Your index.html file already contains an navigation bar. So if you try to present other page in a tab with , it won't show the back button on navigation bar as you have already added navigation bar.

I did some changes in your code. First in your index.html file i had comment out the code which were adding navigation back button. Something like below code.

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive nav-title-slide-ios7" align-title="center">
    <!--<ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">-->
    <!--</ion-nav-back-button>-->
</ion-nav-bar>
```

Next, i had explicitly add navigation button on your page2.html file.

```
<!-- Adding navigation bar on top of page2 with a back button-->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive nav-title-slide-ios7" align-title="center">
       <ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
            <button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c" ng-click="myGoBack()">
                Page 1
            </button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-view  view-title="Login" align-title="left"  cache-view="false" class="logincontent">
      <ion-content scroll="false">
        <ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-top">
          <ion-tab title="Login" href="#/page2/signin">                
            <ion-nav-view name="page2-signin"></ion-nav-view>
          </ion-tab>
          <ion-tab title="Register" href="#/page2/signup">
            <ion-nav-view name="page2-signup"></ion-nav-view>
          </ion-tab>        
        </ion-tabs>     
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

Now in your script.js file add this line after you are presenting page2 template.

```
.state('page2', {
    url: '/page2',
    templateUrl: 'page2.html',
    controller: 'Page2Ctrl' // Adding this line which will invoke controller

  })
```

Atlast add controller function in your script.js file

```
.controller('Page2Ctrl', function($scope,$state,$rootScope) {
  $scope.myGoBack = function(){
     $state.go('page1');
  }
})
```

Now as you will click back button which we had explicitly added in page2.html, above function will get invoke and it will push the state back again to page1. Hope this will help you out.. Happy coding. :)